# Monopoly deal rent

Tags: monopoly-deal

If I rent someone for a large amount of money, but they have no money, or properties, and all they have is a full set, can I take the set as payment?

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing that prevents properties in a monopoly from being used to pay for rent, but the decision belongs to the paying player.

> You can pay with cards from your bank, properties, or a combination of both. You choose how to play - not the player you're paying!

The Sly Deal and Forced Deal cards have exceptions for properties in a set; rent does not have this exception.  So, if a player must pay you rent and all they have are properties in sets, they must pay you using property from those sets.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can take ANYTHING from the enemy players, if they don't have enough cash.

The game really reflects real life scenarios. Where anything can happens, even losing property to opponents.

Hope this answers your question.